# Xcode beginner need help :/

Tags: xcode, appdelegate

I have this problem, what am I doing wrong?

thank you

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

then it says:

`argc = (int)1` &
`argv = (char**) 0xbff9f3bc`

Comment: Is `argc = (int)1 & argv = (char**) 0xbff9f3bc` the error message?

Comment: You're missing a close curly bracket (`}`)  after the third line

Comment: I am sorry, but we cannot help you.  There are thousands of possible issues that could result in this.  You are going to have to give us more information like code, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly bracket.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
} }
```

Comment: That's not his problem; I think it was just a typo when submitting the question.  If that was in his actual code, the program wouldn't even compile, much less crash.

Comment: Hmm. I guess your right. It's the only thing i could find though.

Comment: Right, he didn't provide even close to enough information to debug this.